# How can I use cloud-init with Flatcar on Hetzner?

Tags: cloud-init, coreos-ignition, hcloud

I want to use Flatcar with Cloud-Init on Hetzner Cloud Servers.
After installing flatcar on a server via rescue system i want to create a snapshot from this server and create new servers out of this snapshot.
To these snapshots I want to parse my cloud-init data (the things that are possible with flatcar coreos-cloud-init) to the Hetzner API and customize my Server that way.

The Installation works well (see [flatcar docs](https://www.flatcar.org/docs/latest/installing/cloud/hetzner/#provisioning))
With the installation I parse a small ignition file that adds my ssh-key to the "core" user, this also works well.
After that I generate a new snapshot from this "installation-server".

When i create a new server out of this snapshot I parse cloud-init data to the server but I can not find the user-data file on the server or see some cloud-init stuff happen in the journal.